# What is signal when specifying the CRS of a layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyqgis, layers

What is the signal when the CRS of a layer changes?

I tried `QgsProject.instance().crsChanged`, but this is a signal that happens when the project CRS changes.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example when you feel the CRS of a layer could change?

Comment: This is when only CRS is changed in Layer Properties without Reproject Layer.

Comment: But nobody in their right mind does that? ;-)

Comment: I'm making the layer's CRS appear on the screen, but sometimes there are things that are in Proj4 instead of EPSG code, so I want it to appear on the screen when changing to EPSG code.

Answer (score 7):

It uses the same name: [`crsChanged`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#a81b81909c3788e7a83bb0ea3ccdb1e9c).

```
def crs_changed():
    print("CRS changed")

layer = iface.activeLayer()

###
layer.crsChanged.connect(crs_changed)    
###

### TEST
new_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326")
layer.setCrs(new_crs) # emits crsChanged signal
```

[image]